# Libftdi usb_open() failed

Tags: c, libusb

I’m working on a project using Iridium PTT.  The Iridium hardware hooks up to a satellite, and then into my PC via USB.

The Iridium hardware came with some software that runs on Ubuntu Linux, which runs in Virtual Box on my PC.  The software is written all in C and runs very well in Ubuntu.  But I would like to develop on Windows, using Visual Studios.

The Ubuntu version uses libftdi and libusb (from intra2net) to talk to the hardware.

We got libftdi, libusb and created a project in Visual Studios 2013 Desktop Express Edition.  (I even downloaded Zadig for Windows to check to make sure I had the right USB drivers.  I verified The arrow for the Driver was green for my USB connections to the hardware.)

When the Iridium hardware is connected to the computer four Serial Ports appear in the device manager.  I’m attempting to open one of those serial ports from Windows when I run my program.  I get an error when I try to open one (even though I can open it easily from Ubuntu, running in virtual box, on my same PC).

I'm using some sample code (from Intra2net) called "simple.c" that I’m running in Visual Studios.  I’ve posted it below:

```
/* simple.c

Simple libftdi usage example

This program is distributed under the GPL, version 2
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ftdi.h"

int main(void)
{
    int ret;
    struct ftdi_context *ftdi;
    struct ftdi_version_info version;
    if ((ftdi = ftdi_new()) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ftdi_new failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    version = ftdi_get_library_version();
    printf("Initialized libftdi %s (major: %d, minor: %d, micro: %d, snapshot ver: %s)\n",
        version.version_str, version.major, version.minor, version.micro,
        version.snapshot_str);

    if ((ret = ftdi_usb_open(ftdi, 0x403, 0x6011)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to open ftdi device: %d (%s)\n", ret, ftdi_get_error_string(ftdi));
        ftdi_free(ftdi);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Read out FTDIChip-ID of R type chips
    if (ftdi->type == TYPE_R)
    {
        unsigned int chipid;
        printf("ftdi_read_chipid: %d\n", ftdi_read_chipid(ftdi, &chipid));
        printf("FTDI chipid: %X\n", chipid);
    }

    if ((ret = ftdi_usb_close(ftdi)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "unable to close ftdi device: %d (%s)\n", ret, ftdi_get_error_string(ftdi));
        ftdi_free(ftdi);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    ftdi_free(ftdi);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I’ve only modified two lines from Intra2net's original simple.c:

1. Line 10:  Changed `#include <ftdi.h>` to `#include "ftdi.h"`
2. Line 28:  I changed the original hex numbers in `if ((ret = ftdi_usb_open(ftdi, 0x403, 0x6011)) < 0)` to the numbers used in the Ubuntu C code, for my hardware.

The error I’m getting when I run simple.c is  `unable to open ftdi device: -4 (usb_open() failed)`
This is happening right on line 28 in the `ftdi_usb_open` function.

I’m new to low-level C programming and I’m not sure where to go from here.
What does it mean when I encounter this problem?  How could I go about solving the issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `ftdi_usb_open(ftdi_context, vendor, product)` opens the first device with a given vendor and product ids.

Nothing in your code looks wrong, assuming you are providing correct vendor and product value.

Some things worth checking if you are unable to open the device:

- Windows can do some weird things on auto plug. Try disabling serial enumerator on your COM port. You can access this option in Device Manager->Port Settings->Advanced Settings.
- In the same Advanced Settings, remove `Enable Model Ctrl At Startup`.  Devices that monitor these signals can enter the wrong state after an unplug-replug cycle on USB. [More on this](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Knowledgebase/index.html?disablemodemctrlatstartup.htm) from the ftdi chip vendor.
- Another program claimed the chip's interface before yours. You might have something running that connects automatically on USB devices.

Comment: Thanks for posting that.  I wouldn’t have thought to check any of those things.  I did the first two items and still the result is the same as before.  (I’m not quite sure how I would check to see if another program is using the chip's interface.  So I restarted my computer and ran just Visual Studios.  But the result was still the same.)

Comment: You could try with the closed source [http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/D2XX.htm] (FTDI drivers). API is mostly the same, with sligthly different names. Also be sure the USB port is not only available to your VM.

Comment: Yes you’re right, I should use FTDI’s drivers.  A friend of mine even told me it’s not possible to run libftdi, libusb on Windows (it’s only for Linux).  I confirmed that my Windows 8, PC was using FTDI drivers from reading “How to find out if the device is FTDI-based?” from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37982/Interact-with-FTDI-chip Yep, I was going down the wrong rabbit hole!  Thanks again for all the help!